# How does MVC routing work?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, routes

So I've started studying MVC (real MVC, not framework MVC) a bit more in-depth, and I'm attempting to develop a small framework. I'm working by reading other frameworks such as Symphony and Zend, seeing how they do their job, and attempt to implement it myself.

The place where I got stuck was the URL routing system:

```
<?php
namespace Application\Common;

class RouteBuilder {

    public function create($name, $parameters) {
        $route           = new Route($name);
        $route->resource = array_keys($parameters)[0];
        $route->defaults = $parameters["defaults"];
        $notation        = $parameters["notation"];
        $notation = preg_replace("/\[(.*)\]/", "(:?$1)?", $notation);
        foreach ($parameters["conditions"] as $param => $condition) {
            $notation = \str_replace($param, $condition, $notation);
        }

        $notation = preg_replace("/:([a-z]+)/i", "(?P<$1>[^/.,;?\n]+)", $notation);

        //@TODO: Continue pattern replacement!!
    }
}
/* How a single entry looks like
 * "main": {
    "notation": "/:action",
    "defaults": {
        "resource"  :   "Authentication",
    },
    "conditions":   {
        ":action"   :   "(login)|(register)"
    }
},

 */
```

I just can't get my head wrapped around it properly. What is the application workflow from here?

The pattern is generated, probably a `Route` object to be kept under the `Request` object or something, then what? How does it work?

> **P.S.** Looking for a real, well explained answer here. I really want to understand the subject. I would appreciate if someone took the time to write a real elaborate answer.

Comment: have a look at my blog: www.ganymedes.be

Comment: @JvdBerg: I can't see anything there regarding the routing itself, do you have a more specific link? also a tip, prefix links with http:// so that they're parsed, this way you get the nice SEO bonus :P

Comment: Why not look in to an existing framework, for example, Kohana or Fuel?

Comment: I posted the router class from my framework. Hope it helps.

Comment: @MrtiBriedis: I have, please read the question. I still didn't get it (I wouldn't have asked here if I haven't exhausted all other means.

Comment: I am very glad you asked this. The PHP MVC book by Chris Pitt is not a great place to learn about `Router` classes.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

An MVC `Router` class (which is part of a broader *Front Controller*) breaks down an HTTP request's URL--specifically, the path component (and potentially the query string).

The `Router` attempts to match the first one, or two, parts of the path component to a corresponding route combination (`Controller` / Action [*method*], or just a `Controller` that executes a default action (*method*).

An action, or command, is simply a *method* off of a specific `Controller`.

There is usually an `abstract Controller` and many children of `Controller`, one for each webpage (generally speaking).

Some might say that the `Router` also passes arguments to the desired `Controller`'s method, if any are present in the URL.

**Note**: Object-oriented programming purists, following the Single Responsibility Principle, might argue that *routing* components of a URL and *dispatching* a `Controller` class are two separate responsibilities. In that case, a `Dispatcher`class would actually instantiate the `Controller` and pass one of its methods any arguments derived from the client HTTP request.

**Example 1: `Controller`, but no action or arguments.**

`http://localhost/contact` On a GET request, this might display a form.

*Controller* = Contract

*Action* = Default (commonly an `index()` method)

======================

**Example 2: `Controller` and action, but no arguments.**

`http://localhost/contact/send` On a POST request, this might kick of server-side validation and attempt to send a message.

*Controller* = Contract

*Action* = send

======================

**Example 3: `Controller`, action, and arguments.**

`http://localhost/contact/send/sync` On a POST request, this might kick of server-side validation and attempt to send a message. However, in this case, maybe JavaScript is not active. Thus, to support graceful degradation, you can tell the `ContactController` to use a `View` that supports screen redraw and responds with an HTTP header of `Content-Type: text/html`, instead of `Content-Type: application/json`. `sync` would be passed as an argument to `ContactConroller::send()`. Note, my `sync` example was totally arbitrary and made up, but I thought it fit the bill!

*Controller* = Contract

*Action* = send

*Arguments* = `[sync]`  // Yes, pass arguments in an array!

A `Router` class instantiates the requested, concrete child `Controller`, calls the requested *method* from the *controller instance*, and passes the controller method its *arguments* (if any).

**1)** Your `Router` class should first check to see if there is a concrete `Controller` that it can instantiate (using the name as found in the URL, plus the word "Controller"). If the controller is found, [test for the presence of the requested method](http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php) (action).

**2)** If the `Router` cannot find and load the necessary PHP at runtime (using an [autoloader](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) is advised) to instantiate a concrete `Controller` child, it should then check an array (typically found in another class name `Route`) to see if the requested URL [matches](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), using regular expressions, any of the elements contained within. A basic skeleton of a `Route` class follows.

Note: `.*?` = Zero, or more, of any character, non-capturing.

```
class Route
{
    private $routes = [
        ['url' => 'nieuws/economie/.*?', // regular expression.
         'controller' => 'news',
         'action' => 'economie'],
        ['url' => 'weerbericht/locatie/.*?', // regular expression.
         'controller' => 'weather',
         'action' => 'location']
    ];

    public function __contstruct()
    {

    }

    public function getRoutes()
    {
        return $this->routes;
    }
}
```

Why use a regular expression? One is not likely to get reliable matching accomplished for data after the second forward slash in the URL.

`/controller/method/param1/param2/...`, where param[x] could be *anything*!

**Warning:** It is good practice change the default regular expression pattern delimiter ('/') when targeting data contains the pattern delimiter (in this case, forward slashes '/'. Almost any non-valid URL character would be a great choice.

A method of the `Router` class will iterate over the `Route::routes` array to see if there is a regular expression match between the target URL and the `string` *value* associated with a 2nd level `url` index. If a match is found, the `Router` then knows which concrete `Controller` to instantiate and the subsequent method to call. Arguments will be passed to the method as necessary.

Always be wary of edge cases, such as URLs representing the following.

```
`/`   // Should take you to the home page / HomeController by default
`''`  // Should take you to the home page / HomeController by default
`/gibberish&^&*^&*%#&(*$%&*#`   // Reject
```

Comment: If your version is a simplified example, what advantages does the approach I've seen (i.e. my example) have over yours? Also, what if no match is found?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha The difference between mine and yours is, is that you can specify how the notation should look like. I see you can add certain conditions for the action methods. And some other things. So with other words, your example is more configurable. --- I'm not sure where you got the code from (Symphony?), so i can't really tell what all the options really mean. But the general idea is the very same as my example. Also, if no match is found then a 404 page (404Controller) should be shown. Because the requested page simply doesn't exist.

Comment: Well, shouldn't it default to "resource/action/params"?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Normally in other frameworks the `default` option is the controller/action that should be called when the URI contains no data. Otherwise, when the URI contains data, but isn't found in the `RouteBuilder`, then you should really throw a 404 error. I really wouldn't recommend any other way.

Comment: Either something about this is inaccurate or I'm confused about something: In a test case of a clean apache server without mod rewrite a request like localhost/news does not reroute to localhost/index.php?route=news but results in a 404 error?

Comment: @Assimilater That's why the second line says: "Which is actually **(if you're not using mod rewrite)** something like this:". But if you think this is unclear that the first mentioned URL is a `mod_rewrite` url then you could always propose an edit to clearify things

Comment: The confusion was more it seemed to imply that apache somehow transformed that request into a GET parameter, which doesn't happen. Made an edit proposition.

Answer (score 2):

The router class, from my framework. The code tells the story:

```
class Router
{
  const default_action = 'index';
  const default_controller = 'index';

  protected $request = array();

  public function __construct( $url )
  {
    $this->SetRoute( $url ? $url : self::default_controller );
  }

  /*
  *  The magic gets transforms $router->action into $router->GetAction();
  */
  public function __get( $name )
  {
    if( method_exists( $this, 'Get' . $name ))
      return $this->{'Get' . $name}();
    else
      return null;
  }

  public function SetRoute( $route )
  {
    $route = rtrim( $route, '/' );
    $this->request = explode( '/', $route );
  }

  private function GetAction()
  {
    if( isset( $this->request[1] ))
      return $this->request[1];
    else
      return self::default_action;
  }

  private function GetParams()
  {
    if( count( $this->request ) > 2 )
      return array_slice ( $this->request, 2 );
    else
      return array();
  }

  private function GetPost()
  {
    return $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST';
  }

  private function GetController()
  {
    if( isset( $this->request[0] ))
      return $this->request[0];
    else
      return self::default_controller;
  }

  private function GetRequest()
  {
    return $this->request;
  }
```

Comment: I'm not very comfortable using your code. It contains a lot of global space I don't really want in my code. Also, have you considered using comments? That code is not self-explanatory. I'll have a look nonetheless.

Comment: @JvdBerg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166087/php-global-in-functions/5166527#5166527. Also, your Router shouldnt know anything about the SAPI. Pass the URL in from the outside.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I changed the router class, the SAPI and globals are moved to the bootstrapper. Added some comments

Comment: Not enough error checking. Little, if any security. Makes too many assumptions.

Comment: One line of comment is still not enough to explain what is happening to a novice.