# Best way to control an object existence

Tags: php, codeigniter, doctrine-orm

In many controllers, I need to verify if an object (ID passed in URL) exists.

I actually have this skeleton for each controller :

```
public function my_page($id){

$object = $this->Object_model->getObject($id);

if($object == NULL){ // If id mentions a non-existant object, redirect to home
  redirect("home");
}

/** MYCONTROLLER **/
}
```

Is it the good way, the cleanest way to do that ?

Some other options are helpers / model methods / controller methods... I don't know what is the PHP philosophy for that.

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix your controllers with the task to route the application. First you route and then you instantiate one of your controllers according to the given results.

Maybe this answer about routers clarifies what I mean: [How does MVC routing work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12430181/how-does-mvc-routing-work)

Comment: I don't see how I can do the control if ID exists with CI routing.

Route sends a visitor with URL to my controller, I can't use any function or method except a regex between URL reading and the send to Controller

Answer (score 0):

The answer of your DB query is a boolean, so you must check if it's FALSE, and not NULL

```
public function my_page($id){

  $object = $this->Object_model->getObject($id);

  if($object === FALSE){
    redirect("home");
  }

  /** MYCONTROLLER **/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if ( ! $object = $this->Object_model->getObject( $id ) ) {
        redirect( "home" ) ;       }
```

better would be Object_model always returning something whether there was an error or not.

```
   $object = $this->Object_model->getObject( $id ) ;

   if ( $object->errorFlag == true ) {
   redirect( "sorry/" . $object->errorMsg ) ; }
```

Comment: So I should write something like that for all my controllers that load an object ? It will be quite repetitive no ?

Comment: need to see a use case and some code to respond appropriately.