Stripe return url to outside of public folder
My website is written in MVC PHP.
This places view pages in an app folder outside the domain public folder.
Stripe returns to the public folder after payment and not to the cancel or success pages in the app/views.
I give the complete path to this page on payment but MVC PHP does not see it when it returns from stripe.
I expected the full return path to run the success or cancel page.
This works great for me when testing.
define('STRIPE_SUCCESS_URL', 'https://localhost/stripe/app/payment-success.php'); //Payment success URL 
define('STRIPE_CANCEL_URL', 'https://localhost/stripe/app/payment-cancel.php'); //Payment cancel URL

This does not when live and runs index.php.
define('STRIPE_SUCCESS_URL', 'https://mywebsite.com/stripe/app/payment-success.php'); //Payment success URL 
define('STRIPE_CANCEL_URL', 'https://mywebsite.com/stripe/app/payment-cancel.php'); //Payment cancel URL

I am new to MVC PHP.
Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Pretty unlikely, that stripe itself was willy-nilly changing the URLs. Much more likely, that it redirects back to the URLs a specified - and that your system then redirects somewhere else. Start by verifying that, by checking what is going on in your browser dev tools.

I am sure you are correct that it is not stripe at fault. The redirect is set before it goes to stripe in checkout.php. The return goes exactly where i show above. I just don;t know how to return to a page that is outside the root dir in live mode. Even with the link to the website outlined above. I just don't know how this is done as it is a return and not a website starting index.php

We don't know your local setup, what the document root of localhost actually points to. Could it perhaps be, that https://localhost/stripe/ is the equivalent of just https://mywebsite.com/ - because on your localhost, you put the whole thing into a subfolder named stripe, whereas on your live site the whole app resides directly unter the root folder ...?

Thank you for your input. The main issue with MVC PHP is that the whole website does not reside directly under the root folder. The structure of the "public_html" folder is the landing point that contains the index.php. Above that and outside the root folder is the "app" folder containing all the app files. This is why i cannot directly access these files as it is not available outside the root. That is what i don't know about this setup. How can I run this file outside the root "public_html" folder in the "app" folder?

That's usually the index.php's job in such a setup, to load the required files. Your routing configuration tells it, which files to load for what requested URL. Here a pretty in-depth explanation of it all, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12430181/how-does-mvc-routing-work

Solved,
Thank you so much C3roe.
The reference you gave me was just what I needed to go forward on my learning curve.
